# How to download a webpage in MetroStyle app (WinRT) and C#

Tags: c#, .net, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro

I'm creating a MetroStyle app and I want to use a website API that is based on the HTTP Get methods. For instance to login I should download the XML returned by this URL:

`websitehost.com/api/login.php?u=username&p=password`

The problem is that the new MetroStyle apps won't let me to use many of the methods I've been using for years in .Net so how can I download the returned XML document and parse it?

Comment: well I've simplified it but it's basically something like this.

Comment: You should not be passing usernames and passwords via a url.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might be searching for this:

```
    public async Task<string> DownloadPageStringAsync(string url)
    {
        HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler()
        { UseDefaultCredentials = true, AllowAutoRedirect = true };

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url);
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
```

Comment: Yes, this is the code I have used and it worked correctly. I have posted this somewhere else but I can't seem to find the link. Thanks for the reply. Since I have tested this, I'll set this as answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can use either the [`Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlDocument.LoadFromUriAsync(Uri)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br206269.aspx) method to automatically acquire and parse the XML, or you could manually use a [`Windows.Networking.BackgroundTransfer.DownloadOperation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.backgroundtransfer.downloadoperation.aspx) instance to call the web service and acquire the data, and [`Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlDocument.LoadXml(string)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br206269.aspx) to parse the data.

Comment: Could you please explain how can I use the `DownloadOperation`?

Comment: I'm interested to see how to download files other than XML files.

Comment: There aren't a whole lot of examples, but I can venture the guess that you can get an instance of `DownloadOperation` by calling [`BackgroundDownloader.StartDownloadAsync(Uri, IStorageFile)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.backgroundtransfer.backgrounddownloader.startdownloadasync).

Comment: Isn't there any solution to download the page onto a `string` not an `IStorageFile`?

Comment: I honestly don't know off the top of my head. I'm still acquainting myself with WinRT and the Metro APIs.

Comment: Could you please take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8300986/downloading-webpages-in-winrt-throws-an-exception) ? I've posted this method but I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Maybe you can help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use

```
var data = await (new System.Net.Http.HttpClient()).GetAsync(new Uri("http://wherever"));
```

And then do whatever you need with the data, including loading it with XmlDocument or XElement or whatnot.