# Downloading webpages in WinRT throws an exception

Tags: c#, .net, windows-runtime

I'm using this code to download a web page in my Metro Style app:

```
    public static async Task<string> DownloadPageAsync(string url)
    {
        HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
        handler.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        handler.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url);

        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        string responseBody = response.Content.ReadAsString();
        return responseBody;
    }
```

the problem is that when the line `client.GetAsync(url)` runs, it throws an exception that says:

`An error occurred while sending the request.` From type: `HttpRequestException`.

EDIT:

I've used the InnerException to get more info. The first exception thrown is `SocketException` with the message below:

`An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions`

`at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)`

`at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult ar)`

EDIT 2:
I've downloaded and ran the sample from Microsoft and I get the same error:
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/HttpClient-Upload-Sample-f1abcc4e

[image: The error is shown in the picture]

EDIT 3:
I ran this on another machine and it worked fine. So I guess there's nothing wrong with the code. I copied the solution and it means that there's nothing wrong with the solution either. I'm trying to re-install Windows Developer Preview to see if it fixes my problem.

Comment: Have you verified that the URL is what you really intend to be? Paste the URL into a different user agent (a browser, etc..) to make sure it really replys with what you expect it to.

Comment: I've used `http://www.google.com` to test it. I'm sure the URL is OK.

Comment: Please take a look at the edited post. Maybe the new info help.

Comment: Just for the hell of it, could you try replacing the `HttpClientHandler` with a [`WebRequestHandler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.webrequesthandler(v=VS.110).aspx), which is a more derived class?

Comment: Please take a look at this url: http://www.sharpgis.net/post/2011/10/05/WinRT-vs-Silverlight-Part-7-Making-WebRequests.aspx

Comment: There are two things that I can think of that would cause a `WSAEACCES` socket error; the first is an overly strict firewall, and the second is that you may not have granted the Metro application the `internetClient` capability. See the "Specifying app capabilities" section of [this page on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211380.aspx).

Comment: I've done the 2nd one. I don't know about the first one. I don't have any firewall other than the windows firewall.

Comment: I've disabled Windows Firewall and enabled all the capabilities. None helped.

Comment: Related: [How to download a webpage in MetroStyle app (WinRT) and C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8300197/how-to-download-a-webpage-in-metrostyle-app-winrt-and-c-sharp).

Comment: That is my own question. This is more detailed so I decided to create another question.

Comment: Have you confirmed that the application has the internet capability?

Comment: Just out of curiosity; the webpage you're trying to download is it on a server on your local network (or even localhost). If so the "Internet (Client)" capability doesn't work. You need to add "Home/work Networking" to access it.

Comment: I have that enabled too. Please read the latest edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK. I found the answer. The exception was because I installed NetLimiter product on Windows 8 Developer Preview and somehow it prevented my app from accessing the internet.

**UPDATE:**
First of all, this is the code working in **EVERY** version of Windows 8.

```
    public static async Task<string> DownloadPageAsync(string url)
    {
        try
        {
            HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler { UseDefaultCredentials = true, AllowAutoRedirect = true };
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            string html = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            return html;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return "";
        }
    }
```

Secondly, if this doesn't work, chances are, you have a network-related software preventing your app to access the Internet. One popular case is **proxifier**. If you have proxifier installed *your MetroStyle apps won't be able to access the internet.* To make it work, please refer to my blog at:

http://anoori.me/blog/general/use-proxifier-in-windows-8-without-fiddler2

Comment: I had a feeling it was a firewall problem. ;)

Comment: Thank you. I had to re-install my OS to investigate this. Your answer got me to think about it.

Comment: @AlirezaNoori, I'm getting the exception: "Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel in Windows 8 Metro App" Any Idea? URL: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14158069/the-request-was-aborted-could-not-create-ssl-tls-secure-channel-in-windows-8-me

Comment: @Somnath Does your link start with `https`? I checked and got the error with `https` (hence the SSL error). Try with simple `http` and see if it works.

Comment: It also happens (as I just found out) when you've set your internet options to go through a proxy server.

Answer (score 0):

pretty sure netlimiter was running your internet request through a localhost proxy, and your app didn't have the "local network" capability which would allow such access to the local network