# HttpUtility.HtmlDecode in WinRT

Tags: xml, windows-runtime

Is there an equivalent to [`HttpUtility.HtmlDecode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.htmldecode.aspx) in WinRT? I'm developing a MetroStyle app and want to decode strings that came from a XML doc.

Comment: How are you reading the XML file?

Comment: I'm using the method I posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8300986/downloading-webpages-in-winrt-throws-an-exception

Comment: Does metro not support the classes under `System.Xml`? (although, of course, if it's not really XML, but HTML you might want to look at the HTML Agility Pack)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this answer from a Microsoft employee](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/616ad95f-d8aa-4829-b16c-606f30d0f52e), there's currently no replacement for HtmlDecode in the WinRT that's included in the Windows 8 Developer Preview.

However, there will be a replacement in the next pre-release version of WinRT.

Answer (score 39):

Use System.Net.WebUtility instead

Comment: Is it available for WinRT? I can't check myself at the moment.