# The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel in Windows 8 Metro App

Tags: ssl, windows-8, microsoft-metro, httpclient

I have a list of 350 downloadable image urls. I download 10 images parallely at one shot by running multiple tasks. But after downloading **N** number of images suddenly my code throws the following exception.

> Exception: "An error occurred while sending the request."
>
> InnerException: "The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS
>   secure channel."
>
> StackTrace: "at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n  ...

I have created a **sample project** to reproduce this exception. I have 2 test-cases in my hand. You can download the running test project from [My Sky Drive Here](http://sdrv.ms/XjdHaP). Right click on the file HTTPClientTestCases1and2.zip and download.

**Case 1: Using a single instance HttpClient for all image Download.**

In this case I'm sending parallel request to 10 urls using same HttpClient. In this case download is successful for most of the time. After last successful download of an image wait for minimum 40 seconds (Max 1 minute 40 seconds) to send the next parallel download request for the next batch. One image will definitely fail due to this exception. But so many places its written and suggested to use single HttpClient for multiple request.

```
   public async void DownloadUsingSingleSharedHttpClient(Int32 imageIndex)
    {   
        Uri url = new Uri(ImageURLs[imageIndex]);

        UnderDownloadCount++;

        try
        {
            Byte[] contentBytes = null;

            try
            {
                // Exception IS THROWN AT LINE BELOW 
                HttpResponseMessage response = await _httpClient.GetAsync(url);

                contentBytes = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Download Failed at GetAsync() :" + ex.Message);
                throw ex;
            }

            DownloadedCount++;

            if (OnSuccess != null)
                OnSuccess(this, new DownloadSuccessEventArgs() { Index = imageIndex, Data = contentBytes });
        }
        catch (HttpRequestException hre)
        {
            DownloadFailedCount++;
            if (OnFailed != null)
                OnFailed(hre, null);
        }
        catch (TaskCanceledException hre)
        {   
            DownloadFailedCount++;
            if (OnFailed != null)
                OnFailed(hre, null);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            DownloadFailedCount++;
            if (OnFailed != null)
                OnFailed(e, null);
        }
    }
```

**Case 2: Creating new instance of HttpClient for every image Download**

In this case it just fails very frequently due to same exception while downloading images parallely.

```
public async void DownloadUsingCreatingHttpClientEveryTime(Int32 imageIndex)
{
    Uri url = new Uri(ImageURLs[imageIndex]);

    UnderDownloadCount++;
    try
    {
        Byte[] contentBytes = null;

        using (HttpClientHandler _handler = new HttpClientHandler())
        {
            _handler.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
            _handler.MaxAutomaticRedirections = 4;

            using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(_handler))
            {
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.ExpectContinue = false;
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Keep-Alive", "false");

                try
                {
                    // Exception IS THROWN AT LINE BELOW 
                    contentBytes = await httpClient.GetByteArrayAsync(url.OriginalString);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Download Failed :" + ex.Message);
                    throw ex;
                    }
                }

            _handler.Dispose();
        }

        DownloadedCount++;

        if (OnSuccess != null)
            OnSuccess(this, new DownloadSuccessEventArgs() { Index = imageIndex, Data = contentBytes });
    }
    catch (HttpRequestException hre)
    {
        DownloadFailedCount++;
        if (OnFailed != null)
            OnFailed(hre, null);
    }
    catch (TaskCanceledException hre)
    {
        DownloadFailedCount++;
        if (OnFailed != null)
            OnFailed(hre, null);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        DownloadFailedCount++;
        if (OnFailed != null)
            OnFailed(e, null);
    }
}
```

**Please edit the following function in MainPage.xaml.cs to check two cases**

```
 private void Send10DownloadRequestParallel()
    {
        for (Int32 index = 0; index < 10; index++)
        {
            Task.Run(() =>
            {   
                Int32 index1 = rand.Next(0, myImageDownloader.ImageURLs.Count - 1);

                UpdateDownloadProgress();

                // Case 1: Download Using Single Shared HttpClient
                // myImageDownloader.DownloadUsingSingleSharedHttpClient(index1);

                // OR

                // Case 2: Download Using Creating Http Client Every Time
                myImageDownloader.DownloadUsingCreatingHttpClientEveryTime(index1);
            });
        }
    }
```

**My Question:** What I'm doing wrong? What is the best way of implementing parallel downloader in WinRT by overcoming this exception.

Comment: Is it correct to assume that your images are hosted under an SSL location?

Comment: @chuex Yes. As an example images are hosted in Facebook or twitter server.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have a test server with an SSL site to try your code on. If it helps, I was able to run your code on a non-SSL test server - it works just fine in this (non-SSL) case.

Comment: @chuex, you can try this link https://api.twitter.com/1/users/profile_image?screen_name=indiacoupons&size=bigger

Comment: I tried the code using your SSL link and everything worked for me. Here's some sample code that downloads (20 times) your SSL based image https://gist.github.com/4478284 All the code does is create 5 downloads (at a time) and then waits until those 5 downloads are complete.  It repeats this until all files are downloaded.

Comment: @chuex There is one more conduction I just found. If I keep my App ideal for 2 mints. I get the same exception for next normal HTTP POST connection also. Any idea?

Comment: Sorry, but your first 2 sentences do not make sense to me.

Comment: @chuex Test cases: 1) It does not depend upon whether you are sending request to http or https url. Exception is thrown randomly. 2) If you try downloading Images parallely in multiple thread. You may get same exception. Exception is thrown randomly. Yes I'm working with multiple thread to download images parallely. 3) Soon after first 10 downloads if you wait for 2 mints and again send request then it may throw same exception.

Comment: Please update your original question to include a full example... I would like to help you, but I do not have the time to write a multi-threading downloader to try to reproduce the exceptions.

Comment: @chuex I have updated the example. I have created a sample project to reproduce this exception. You can download the running test project from My Sky Drive http://sdrv.ms/XjdHaP. Right click on the file HTTPClientTestCases1and2.zip and download.

Answer (score 2):

I ran your sample application and am only get errors in a couple of scenarios:

1. When the image that your app is requesting does not exist, the .NET HTTP client throws an exception. Your handler doesn't quite handle this case, as the inner exception is NULL.  I had to tweak that code just a little:

   ```
   async void myImageDownloader_OnFailed(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       await App.CurrentDispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, delegate
       {   
           TimeSpan time =(DateTime.Now -dateTimeSuccess);

           String timeGap = "Ideal For:" + time.ToString() + "\n";
           ErrorListBox.Text += "\n Failed When: " + DownloadInfo.Text + "\n";
           ErrorListBox.Text += timeGap;

           // CX - added null check for InnerException, as these are NULL on HTTP result status 404
           var ex = sender as Exception;
           if (ex.InnerException != null)
               ErrorListBox.Text += ex.InnerException.Message;
           else
               ErrorListBox.Text += "Inner Exception null - Outer = (" + ex.ToString() + ")";
       });
   }
   ```
2. The only time I got your other error `Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel in Windows 8 Metro App`, is when I was using a HTTP debugging proxy (Fiddler).  If I don't user Fiddler, which intercepts all HTTP(S) calls, then I have no problems downloading.  I even started multiple downloads in rapid succession (by clicking the blue download area multiple times within one second).  The result was that all items were downloaded (except for the 404 errors, as mentioned above).

Here is a screenshot of the successful downloads (again except for the 404s).  This screenshot is running test case #2 (multiple instances of HttpClient).  I did run test case #1 (single instance of HttpClient) and the results were also successful.

[image: Test application screenshot]

In short, I did not see the problems that you are experiencing.  The only thing I can think of is for you to try your app from a different machine or location.

Comment: +1, Which Url is throwing exception 404? Can you share that url? Can you try that url in Browser and see if it throws 404.

Comment: @Somnath - I could only get one this time (there may or may not be others): https://api.twitter.com/1/users/profile_image?screen_name=TheKatherineWeb&size=bigger  I tried in a browser and it is not found.  You really should Google `Fiddler proxy`. It is really handy in these scenarios, as it shows what requests are being made, and which ones succeeded or failed.